# Как правильно создать абстрактный метод

Tags: java, android, eventbus

```
@Subscribe
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {

}
```

Как добавить интерфейс в абстрактный класс таким образом, чтобы `@Subscribe` тоже появлялся.

А то только

```
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {

}
```

Comment: от greenbota EventBus жи

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/352301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если открыть исходники EventBus и конкретно [описания данной аннотации](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/EventBus/src/org/greenrobot/eventbus/Subscribe.java), то мы увидим, что она НЕ помечена как "Inherited"

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Subscribe {.....
```

Соответственно она не наследуется.

Comment: Но IDEA ругается из - за этого и не компилируется проект. Это надо обратиться к кампанию Greenbot и просить чтобы они сделали наследственной? или как то в Android studio можно этот момент решить?

Comment: @EraNewGames Не видя ваш код и ошибку я не могу сказать, на что и почему ругается среда разработки. Подозреваю, что ругается она на отсутствующий метод в классе наследнике, что логично. По поводу добавления Inherited к описанию аннотации вот тут разработчик объясняет https://github.com/google/guava/issues/783